# Using added value in Drop Down List

Tags: language-agnostic

Currently, I have received a piece of code to work with. There is a dropdownlist which displays the grade/year of student (Prep - Year 12). The "Prep" value is added to the Dropdownlist by this code, I believe:

```
Public Sub PopulateGradeWithPrep(ByRef ddlYear As DropDownList, ByVal intMax As Integer, ByVal intMin As Integer)
            Dim iLoop As Integer

            'populate year ddl

            If ddlYear.Items.Count = 0 Then
                For iLoop = intMin To intMax
                    If (iLoop = 0) Then
                        ddlYear.Items.Add(New ListItem("Prep", CStr(iLoop)))
                    Else
                        ddlYear.Items.Add(CStr(iLoop))
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End Sub
```

The name of the dropdownlist is YearLevelAdmission, the is a code to populate the data from the above code to it which is this:

```
 Private Sub PopulateScreenList(ByVal strYearLevelAdmission As String)
        'Populate year level admission
        slco.PopulateGradeWithPrep(ddlYearLevelAdmission, 12, 0)
        'populate year level admission value
        If Not slco.IsStringBlank(strYearLevelAdmission) Then
            slco.SelectItemInDDList(ddlYearLevelAdmission, strYearLevelAdmission)
        End If
```

slco is Module Common. The First code was written in .vb file.

Those 2 code above are given to me and I am using code behind, trying to select the value of "Prep", then some of the panel will be invisible. This is my code:

```
If ddlYearLevelAdmission.SelectedValue ="Prep" Then
panel1.visible= false
panel2.visible = false
Else
panel1.visible = true
panel2.visible = true
End If
```

The problem is when I select Prep, there is auto post back but nothing change, the two panels are still there. I have been stuck for a day already.

Help is really appreciated

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

When you add "Prep" to DropDown you are actually adding a ListItem, not a string. I believe you ment to add a string - instead of

```
ddlYear.Items.Add(New ListItem("Prep", CStr(iLoop)))
```

you should write

```
ddlYear.Items.Add("Prep")
```

Comment: Then we are looking at wrong code. Could you please put a breakpoint to  If ddlYearLevelAdmission.SelectedValue ="Prep" Then  and verify type and value of "SelectedValue"?